# SuiteScript 2.0: Dynamically add search results to custom column list based on selected Account line

Tags: javascript, netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0, suitescript1.0

Hope you can assist.

I am trying to add the results of a saved search into a custom column list I created 'on-the-fly' using an user event script. I have historically been successful using SuiteScript 1.0 but now transitioning to 2.0, it does not seem possible.

To demonstrate my code, I first build a UE script, creating a custom column list using the 'serverWidget' module:

```
            if (recordType === 'journalentry') {
            log.debug('works')
            var objLineSublist = getForm.getSublist({id: 'line'});

            // Add several custom fields to the form
            var entityField = objLineSublist.addField({
                id: 'custpage_entity',
                type: serverWidget.FieldType.SELECT,
                label: 'Entity'
            });
        }
```

My UE script works fine.

I now create a client script; first checking the account type is A/R or A/P, and depending on which of these are selected, the custom list (custpage_entity) will populate with customer or vendor data from a saved search. As this is a client script, I cannot access the properties of the serverWidget module to capture the sublist fields (same way I used it on the UE script). I noticed the "currentRecord.getField" object which I could use instead but sadly did not work. Here is my code:

```
                var customEntity = currentRecord.getField({fieldId: 'custpage_entity'});
            log.debug('customEntity', customEntity);

            if (getAcctType === 'AcctRec' || getAcctType === 'AcctPay') {

                var recordType = '';
                if (getAcctType === 'AcctRec')
                    recordType = 'customer'
                else recordType = 'vendor';
                log.debug('getAcctType', getAcctType + ' | ' + recordType);

                // Insert a blank option.
                customEntity.insertSelectOption({ value: 'test', text: 'test' })

                //Execute saved search
                var getCustomerResults = getEntityListFromSearch(recordType);

                getCustomerResults.run().each(function(result){
                    // .run().each has a limit of 4,000 results
                    customEntity.insertSelectOption({
                        value: result.getValue({name: 'internalid'}),
                        text: result.getValue({name: 'entityid'})
                    })
                    return true;
                });

            }
```

If you can assist what I am doing wrong, that would be most helpful!
I should note: I need this to work on FIELDCHANGE of the 'account' column field in the client script.

Answer (score 0):

You need to insert your options in the dropdown from the server side (UE script) or in a pageInit event in the client script (but this would only work without your fieldChange)

I would suggest to create two different dropdowns in the UE script and insert the options one for vendors and one for customers and add a CSS class to hide them. In the fieldChange event display the correct dropdown based on the user selection using CSS.

Comment: Thanks @Emerson, do you have any example you can share to do this?